# Rolling root mean square instead of mean in r

Tags: r, rolling-computation

Let's say I have 1-hour data and I can aggregate the data to 2-hour and 3-hour data by rolling mean with the codes below.

```
library(zoo)
h1<-c(2, 4, 6)
h2<-rollmean(h1,2)
h3<-rollmean(h1,3)
```

Here's what I got from this:

```
h2
[1] 3 5

h3
[1] 4
```

But I want to use `root mean square` function below instead of `mean` function while aggregating.

```
sqrt(mean(x^2))
```

Here are the desired outputs:

```
h2_rms
[1] 3.162278 5.099020
h3_rms
[1] 4.320494
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply your own functions with `rollapply` :

```
library(zoo)

h1<-c(2, 4, 6)
rms <- function(x) sqrt(mean(x^2))

h2 <- rollapply(h1,2, rms)
h3 <- rollapply(h1,3, rms)

h2
#[1] 3.162278 5.099020

h3
#[1] 4.320494
```

Comment: Also `sqrt(rollmean(h1^2, k))`